# click event without open a new tab in selenium but WindowHandles.Count == 1 C#

Tags: c#, webdriver

I'm making a Crawler

`driver.FindElement(By,Id("Link")).Click();`

It  opens a new tab, but the count of `driver.WindowHandles` is one or two. Why?

Comment: Please share HTML and Problem in Detail